# How do I get webpack to process scss files into css, but copy them to a custom location?

Tags: webpack

In my current configuration, I managed to get Webpack to either transpile the scss files (scss-loader, css-loader, style-loader...) , and then bundle the result in a single css file, or I managed to get the scss files individually copied inside the /dist directory where I want them.

Copy into a style.css:

```
test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
use: [
  'style-loader',
  'css-loader',
  'sass-loader'
]
```

Copy into /dist, within the same tree as they have in /src

```
new CopyPlugin({
  patterns: [
    { from: 'src/**/*.{css,scss}' },
    'src/templates/pages/styleguide'
  ],
  options: {
    concurrency: 100
  }
})
```

How do I get Webpack to transpile the scss files first, and then copy them individually into /dist according to, say, their component name (same structure I have in source)?

```
/dist
  /components
    component-a/component-a.css
    component-b/component-b.css
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is dependent on what version `Webpack` you are using, and the `filepath` you are working with.

The docs for `mini-css-extract-plugin` have an example using [filename option as function](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/#filename-option-as-function).

> With the filename option you can use chunk data to customize the filename. This is particularly useful when dealing with multiple entry points and wanting to get more control out of the filename for a given entry point/chunk. In the example below, we'll use filename to output the generated css into a different directory.

`webpack.config.js`

```js
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: ({ chunk }) => `${chunk.name.replace("/src/", "/dist/")}.css`,
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
```

So for example, if your files are

```
/src
  /components
    component-a/component-a.css
    component-b/component-b.css
```

You can try replacing the `src` for `dist` and see if that works.

```
/dist
  /components
    component-a/component-a.css
    component-b/component-b.css
```

You could also check out these other examples using the `mini-css-extract-plugin` with `Webpack` that *may* work.

1. [Public path option as function](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/#the-publicpath-option-as-function)
2. [Extracting css based on entry](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/#extracting-css-based-on-entry)